# node-sass not applying styles from node_modules

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, node-sass

I am importing scss file from a node_module this way (in tsx file)-

```
import "@package-name/sass/index.scss"
```

Also tried creating a local index.scss and importing this way -

```
@import "~@package-name/sass/index.scss"
```

I am using create-react-app with node-sass installed.
Styles from all local scss files are applied but not from scss file imported from a node_module.

I have tried importing raw css files from node_module too. It too did not work.

Can anybody help me solve this issue?

(Not in a situation to run npm enject and modify webpack configs from create-react-app)